# How many real solutions does $a^{a^{a^x}}=b^{b^{b^x}}$ have?

Tags: equation-solving

Let `b > a && a > 1`, then the equation `a^x==b^x` has the unique real solution `x==0`. The equation `a^a^x==b^b^x`  also has the only real solution as

```
Reduce[a^a^x == b^b^x && b > a && a > 1, x, Reals]
```

> `Log[a/b] != 0 && a > 1 && b > a && x == -(Log[Log[a]/Log[b]]/Log[a/b])`

shows. However,

```
Reduce[a^a^a^x == b^b^b^x && b > a && a > 1, x, Reals]
```

is running without any response on my computer for a long time (Maybe, an infinite loop is executing.). How many real solutions does this equation have? It should be noticed that

```
a=2;b=3;Reduce[a^a^a^x == b^b^b^x, x, Reals]
```

> `False`

at once.

Addition.

```
a = 343;b = a^3;Reduce[a^a^a^x == b^b^b^x, x, Reals]//N
```

> `x == -0.259182 || x == -0.142664`

```
a=2^8;b=a^2;Reduce[a^a^a^x == b^b^b^x, x, Reals]
```

> `x==-1/4`

Comment: I think that for `a>1` and all real values of `x`, `a^a^a^x` is a monotonically increasing function of `a`.  This means that `b>a` implies `b^b^b^x>a^a^a^x`.  (Note that `a^x>0` implies `a^a^x>1`)

Comment: @mikado: Can you ground your " This means that `b>a` implies `b^b^b^x>a^a^a^x`"? BTW, `a^a^x` is an increasing function on the real axis, but this does not imply `b^b^x > a^a^x` for all real  `x`.

Comment: For `a=2`, `b=3` try `Plot[a^a^a^x - b^b^b^x, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-20, 10}]` to see what is happening.

Comment: How can I save the question from its edits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beginning with the equation

```
eq = a^(a^(a^x)) == b^(b^(b^x))
```

set `b -> a^c` with `c > 1`.

```
% /. b -> a^c
(* a^a^a^x == (a^c)^(a^c)^(a^x)^c *)
```

The key step is recognizing that that `(a^x)^c` equals `(a^c)^x`.

```
% /. (a^c)^x -> (a^x)^c
(* a^a^a^x == (a^c)^(a^c)^(a^x)^c *)
```

Next, set `a^x` to `y`, which must be positive.

```
% /. a^x -> y
(* a^a^y == (a^c)^(a^c)^y^c *)
```

and twice take the `Log` of both sides.

```
s = FullSimplify[ApplySides[Log[Log[#]] &, %], a > 1 && y > 0 && c > 1]
(* (y - c*y^c)*Log[a] == Log[c] *)
```

If `c` is an integer, `s` is a polynomial that can be solved in terms of `Root`.  For instance, with `c -> 3`

```
Reduce[(s /. c -> 3) && a > 1 && y > 0, y, Reals]
(* (a == 81 Sqrt[3] && y == Root[Log[3] - Log[a] #1 + 3 Log[a] #1^3 &, 2]) || 
    (a > 81 Sqrt[3] && (y == Root[Log[3] - Log[a] #1 + 3 Log[a] #1^3 &, 2] || 
                        y == Root[Log[3] - Log[a] #1 + 3 Log[a] #1^3 &, 3])) *)
```

and `x -> Log[y]/Log[a]`.  Choosing `a -> 343` then yields the first specific solution given in the question.  To obtain the second specific solution in the question, use

```
Reduce[(s /. c -> 2) && a > 1 && y > 0, y, Reals]
(* (a == 256 && y == 1/4) || 
   (a > 256 && (y == 1/4 - 1/4 Sqrt[(-8 Log[2] + Log[a])/Log[a]] || 
                y == 1/4 + 1/4 Sqrt[(-8 Log[2] + Log[a])/Log[a]])) *)
```

**Addendum: Results for non-integer c**

The symbolic solutions obtained above are for integer `c`.  However, numerical solutions for specific values of `a` can be obtained without difficulty from `s`, for instance.

```
NSolve[s /. {c -> Pi, a -> 343}, y, Reals] // Flatten
(* {y -> 0.225106, y -> 0.447724} *)
```

The symbolic solutions also provide the value of `a` above which there are two real solutions and below which there are none.  An alternative approach to obtaining this `a` that is applicable for all `c > 1` turns out to be straightforward.

```
sy = Simplify[Solve[D[Subtract @@ s, y] == 0 && c > 1 && y > 0, y][[1, 1]],
    c > 1]
(* y -> c^(-2/(-1 + c)) *)

FullSimplify[ApplySides[Exp, s /. sy], a > 1 && c > 1];
sa = a -> c ^(1 / %[[1, 2]])
(* a -> c^(1/((-1 + c)*c^((1 + c)/(1 - c)))) *)
```

(Surprisingly, `sa = Reduce[% && a > 1 && c > 1, a, Reals]` instead of `sa = a -> c ^(1 / %[[1, 2]])` returns unevaluated!)  For completeness, here are plots of the two quantities just derived.

```
Plot[sa // Last, {c, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 250}, 
    AxesLabel -> {c, Subscript[a, min]}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[sy // Last, {c, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {c, y[Subscript[a, min]]}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

For large `c` this minimum value of `a` approaches `c`, and the corresponding value of `y` approaches `1`.

Comment: +1. Deep thought. The presentation of the answer may be improved. Do you obtain the discriminant set as `RegionPlot[(1 - Log[a]/Log[b])  (Log[b]/Log[a])^(-(      2/(-1 + Log[b]/Log[a]))) >= Log[Log[b]/Log[a]]/Log[a] &&    b > a, {a, 1, 4000}, {b, 1, 40000}, PlotPoints -> 100]`? I need some time to think about it.  I'll be waiting for other answers some time too.